# How to switch external css file based on user input in rshiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am looking to build a dark mode in my application. I realize we can achieve that using bs_theme(), but my application has many more settings in an external css file that do not get read when I use bs_theme().

I want to have 2 separate CSS files, one for light theme and one for dark theme. Based on the user input, the relevant theme file should be loaded in my Rshiny app. Any suggestion on how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create two different [css classes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) in this case.

[Here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) you'll find how to include css files (as many as you like) into a shiny app.

To switch between the classes we can use `addCssClass`/ `removeCssClass` (or `toggleCssClass`) from `library(shinyjs)`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

if(!dir.exists("www")){
  dir.create("www")
}

writeLines(".dark {
  background-color: black;
  color: white; /* text color */
}", con = "www/dark_mode.css")

writeLines(".light {
  background-color: white;
  color: black; /* text color */
}", con = "www/light_mode.css")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "dark_mode.css"),
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "light_mode.css")
  ),
  radioButtons("mode", "Select mode", choices = c("dark", "light"), selected  = "light")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$mode, {
    if(input$mode == "dark"){
      addCssClass(class = "dark", selector = "body")
      removeCssClass(class = "light", selector = "body")
    } else {
      addCssClass(class = "light", selector = "body")
      removeCssClass(class = "dark", selector = "body")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

The same can be done via [Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html) and some custom JS using e.g. `element.classList.add("myclass");` (see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp)).

---

**Edit: Apply `addCssClass` to inputs of different classes:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

if(!dir.exists("www")){
  dir.create("www")
}

writeLines(".dark {
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white; /* text color */
}", con = "www/dark_mode.css")

writeLines(".light {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: black; /* text color */
}", con = "www/light_mode.css")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "dark_mode.css"),
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "light_mode.css")
  ),
  radioButtons("mode", "Select mode", choices = c("dark", "light"), selected  = "light"),
  selectizeInput("Test", "Test Input", choices = 1:10),
  actionButton("testButton", "Test Button")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$mode, {
    applyTo <- list(".selectize-input", ".btn-default")
    if(input$mode == "dark"){
      lapply(applyTo, function(x){
        addCssClass(class = "dark", selector = x)
        removeCssClass(class = "light", selector = x)
      })
    } else {
      lapply(applyTo, function(x){
        addCssClass(class = "light", selector = x)
        removeCssClass(class = "dark", selector = x)
      })
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

---

**Edit: using `forEach`:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

if(!dir.exists("www")){
  dir.create("www")
}

writeLines(".dark {
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white; /* text color */
}", con = "www/dark_mode.css")

writeLines(".light {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: black; /* text color */
}", con = "www/light_mode.css")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "dark_mode.css"),
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "light_mode.css")
  ),
  radioButtons("mode", "Select mode", choices = c("dark", "light"), selected  = "light"),
  selectizeInput("Test", "Test Input", choices = 1:10),
  actionButton("testButton", "Test Button")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dm_classes <- paste(c(".selectize-input", ".btn-default"), collapse = ", ")
  
  observeEvent(input$mode, {
    if(input$mode == "dark"){
      runjs(sprintf("document.querySelectorAll('%s').forEach(x=>x.classList.add('dark'));
                     document.querySelectorAll('%s').forEach(x=>x.classList.remove('light'));", dm_classes, dm_classes))
    } else {
      runjs(sprintf("document.querySelectorAll('%s').forEach(x=>x.classList.add('light'));
                     document.querySelectorAll('%s').forEach(x=>x.classList.remove('dark'));", dm_classes, dm_classes))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @ismirsehregal, while your approach works but how do I go about customizing specific elements styles? For ex, the below setting should only be applied for light mode:
`
.light .selectize-input, .selectize-control.single .selectize-input.input-active {
  background-color:red;
  border:0px;
}
`
However, I am seeing this change in for both light and dark mode. In the dark mode css, i have kept the color to be be white and appended the class .dark to it.

Comment: Here is the dark mode css setting, so that there is no confusion:
.dark .selectize-input, .selectize-control.single .selectize-input.input-active {
  background-color:#738ca5;
  border:0px;
}

Comment: @shivam_data_scientist please see my edit.

Comment: Hi @ismirsehregal, thanks for the solution. It works the way you have put it, however, I feel this would get very slow as we add more and more elements to the list. Don't you think?

Comment: @shivam_data_scientist we can use JS instead - please see my edit.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks a bunch @ismirsehregal! I have accepted your answer as the solution, because it does answer the original question.
But one more thing I would want to know is if you know how the same can be approached using sass? Please let me know if that is a whole new question on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CSS files are named **darkmode.css** and **lightmode.css**, and are placed into the **www** subfolder, you can use `renderUI` like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    uiOutput("css")
  ),
  radioButtons("select", "Select mode", c("dark", "light"))
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  output[["css"]] <- renderUI({
    cssfile <- paste0(input[["select"]], "mode.css")
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = cssfile)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]